Connection Settings (WAN/LAN) for MC888 Ultra 5G router stuck on grey
I don't have the default user name and password for the PPPoE option but I'm trying to understand why is it greyed out and it doesn't let me choose the "Dynamic IP" option which does not require user name and password.


Did you find a solution? I have the same problem. Elias
